# Editing stylized output on Mathematica Online

Tags: mathematica-online

Suppose the output of Mathematica involves a square-root, such as shown in the image below, taken from Mathematica Online.

[image]

If one copies the output and pastes into a new input cell, the content inside the square-root is uneditable. Is there any way around that with the online version of Mathematica?

I'm teaching students to use the program, and using the online version has many advantages over having to install software. There are times where it is useful to copy output cells and use them as input in other places with some alteration. That seems hard to do in the online version. (There are work-arounds, but I'd like to be able to do this.)

Comment: CTRL-SHIFT-I converts the cell to input form for me (Mac, Safari), which is editable. Maybe that will work for you. It converts the whole cell, even if you select only part of the cell. -- Don't know where to find these things out. Mine was a wild guess.

Comment: In Chrome, CTRL + SHIFT + I opens the Developer Tools. One would think that your key-combination would align to something in the menu, but I can't find anything.

Comment: I found a gear-wheel icon near the cell bracket. Click on it and the popup menu has a "Convert to" submenu. In that submenu, there is "InputForm" to click.  See if you can do that.

Comment: That works. Put that as an answer and I'll mark it correct.